# wcf json client trailing forward slash escaped

Tags: wcf, json, rest

I'm using WCF as a client to contact a REST service that accepts and returns JSON data.

The service is located at **http://127.0.0.1/REST/get_details/** *-- Note the trailing forward slash*

Unfortunately WCF escapes the trailing forward slash before calling the url so the call fails.  I can't use the **UriTemplate** property of WebInvoke because this is a webscript call so it's not allowed and the **Action** and **ReplyAction** of **[OperationContract]** are for SOAP not REST so I can't use them either.

The incorrect url this call results in is: **/REST/get_details_x002F_**

How can I stop WCF from messing up the url?

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://127.0.0.1/REST/")]
public interface IDetailsSvc
{
    [OperationContract(Name = "get_details/")]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    DetailsResponse GetDetails(string id);
}
```

Comment: Fortunately I was able to ask the developers on the other end to not require the forward slash but I would still like to see if anyone has a better solution to this.  You're not always blessed with being able to ask for these things to be changed.

Comment: You should really drop the trailing slash, it is not necessary and leads to confusion as you've discovered. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah... I'm not using the  config tag correctly.  You only specify this on service endpoints not client endpoints.  It makes no sense to specify it on an endpoint that you are implementing in a client.

"This element enables the endpoint behavior that makes it possible to consume the service from ASP.NET AJAX web pages."
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675191.aspx